# Move login toggle to account section in checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I want to move the Login toggle bar in the Woocommerce Checkout page into the first column below the email address field.

I have included an image of what I am referring to. [Checkout page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQWIA.png)

Here is what I have tried:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_form_login', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_registration_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_form_login_custom' );
function woocommerce_checkout_form_login_custom() {
    echo '<tr class="login-form">';
    
    wc_get_template(
        'checkout/form-login.php',
        array(
            'checkout' => WC()->checkout(),
        )
    );
    echo '</tr></td>';
}
```

However, this does not work as it messes up the layout of the 2 column checkout.

If someone can help that would be really appreciated.

Comment: For the remove action you could use `function action_woocommerce_before_checkout_form() { remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_login_form', 10 );
} add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'action_woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 9 );` 
For the other part several adjustments are needed, renaming classes, formatting via CSS and functionality via jQuery